# Trouble configuring GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

Getting errors in one of my classes, "cannot find symbol". What am i doing wrong here?
Do I need to declare them before hand?

Getting errors in one of my classes, "cannot find symbol". What am i doing wrong here?
Do I need to declare them before hand?

Trying to make it look like this:

[image: Add Airport]

```
package userInterface;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;



/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class AddAirport {
    private JPanel mainPane;


public AddAirport(JPanel mainPane){


GridBagLayout gridBagLayout;
gridBagConstraints constraints;
JPanel buttonPane;
JPanel dataPane;
BorderLayout borderLayout;
JButton addBtn;
JButton canxBtn;
JLabel newAirport;
JLabel enterName;
JTextField airportName;
JLabel enterCity;
JTextField airportCity;
JLabel selectState;
JComboBox airportState;
JLabel enterCode;



}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo:

```
    gridBagConstraints constraints;
```

should be

```
    GridBagConstraints constraints;
```

(capital G). Good luck!

Comment: That did work, thanks! But i'm still having the error with JLabel, JTextframe, etc.

Comment: Could you provide the entire stack trace and all of your classes that are involved in it?

Comment: Now it does get rid of the errors, but nothing is showing in that part of the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You never imported any of the Swing classes other than a JPanel and JButton. You also need to import the Labels,  TextFields, ComboBoxes, etc.

You're trying to run your GUI with a bunch of unimported classes / resources.

It's not resource friendly, but 
`import javax.swing.*`
 should fix your problems... for now...

Comment: Now it does get rid of the errors, but nothing is showing in that part of the GUI?

Comment: You don't instantiate or add any of those components to a frame or content pane. Nor do you ever use the panel reference that you pass to your constructor.

Comment: 1 of 2 things: 1) Go back and look over the sun tutorials for GUI creation and manipulation, 2) Go back and learn basic Java. You are missing major concepts here about basic object creation and instantiation

Comment: would it be like                                                                               GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new Gridbaglayout (x);

Comment: Yes and no, GridBagLayout takes no parameters. And I still think you're missing the bigger picture here. You don't even have a skeleton of a GUI here, no main method, nothing. Just uninstantiated variables that are private to your constructor. You don't have anything in correct scope, etc. You literally have nothing here, it won't show or do a thing. Please, please go back and look at the Sun Swing Tutorials.